# Full internet browser in Android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create an android app that when it starts, shows my website. With no option nor URL change. I want a full screen browser without the ability to change the page url.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) widget. First define the resource in a main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webkit"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Now load the resource and display your page:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   WebView browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
   browser.loadUrl("http://yourpage.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView`. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use webview property here in your case ..

A WebView has several customization points where you can add your own behavior. These are:

> - Creating and setting a WebChromeClient subclass. This class is called when something that might impact a browser UI happens, for instance, progress updates and JavaScript alerts are sent here (see Debugging Tasks).
> - Creating and setting a WebViewClient subclass. It will be called when things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors or form submissions. You can also intercept URL loading here (via shouldOverrideUrlLoading()).
> - Modifying the WebSettings, such as enabling JavaScript with setJavaScriptEnabled().
> - Injecting Java objects into the WebView using the addJavascriptInterface(Object, String) method. This method allows you to inject Java objects into a page's JavaScript context, so that they can be accessed by JavaScript in the page.

You can find more information here from android devoelepors below the link..:)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html